# Unity c# and c++ struct Mapping

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine

I am using Unity 2017, in my poject, i used a c++ dll file to define my user information struct, something like:

```
c++ :
struct UserInfo
{ 
  int  userID;
  int  loginID;
  char username[32];
  char signature[128];
  long long goldNum;
  int deskID;
}
```

while i define a struct in c# like:

```
C#:
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct UserInfo
{
  System.Int32 userID;
  System.Int32 loginID;
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
  public string username;
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)]
  public string signature;
  public System.Int64 goldNum;
  System.Int32 deskID;
}
```

finally, i can't get the right username string, it's empty.

wnhen i change the " public string username " to " public byte[] username " it work fine.

how can i get a string data but not a byte[] data , because i need to change the string to a lua file?

Thank you for helping!

Comment: Just to verify I understand you correctly. When you try to send a byte[] from your C++ to your C#, it works fine. But you wish to send a string instead of a byte[]. Is this correct?

Comment: @Doh09 Yes, that's it. i use byte[] in c#  to contain the char[] content in c++, it's OK, but when i change using string in c# i got empty.

Comment: @TJWolschon That's  a different question. It shows how to return c string to C#. This question is asking how to use marshaling to automatically do it.

Comment: @Obso_lu I think I know what the issue is. Update your question and show **every** variable in the `UserInfo` struct  in both C++ and C# side. That's important to answer your question.

Comment: @Programmer  sorry, i just come back from my vacation. i updated the struct variable,can you please have a look  what's wrong with the code?

Answer (score -1):

Disclaimer: I am not experienced in converting between C++ and C#.

That said, I believe that the system does not directly know how to convert a char array into a string.

However, you can use this method to convert at least a C# char array to a C# string. Perhaps it works between languages too.

```
char[] charArray = {'1', '2', '3'};
string s = new string(charArray);
```

So perhaps try to store your c++ char array in a C# char array and then afterwards convert it to a string.

let me know if that works :-)

Comment: `char` in C# is two bytes a piece, which is why the direct conversion to a string isn't working in the first place.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.